# Invalid input syntax for type interval in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, date-arithmetic

I have a query like the following

```sql
CAST(kokyaku1Information2.mail_jyushin as integer) as information2_mail_jyushin,
(date '$mytime' - INTERVAL 'information2_mail_jyushin' day) AS modified_date,
```

When run the query i get an error like `invalid input syntax for type interval`. I used another select field named information2_mail_jyushin before day.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Postgres, you would use interval arithmetics like this:

```
kyaku1Information2.mail_jyushin::int AS information2_mail_jyushin,
date '$mytime' 
    - kokyaku1Information2.mail_jyushin::int * interval '1 day' 
    AS modified_date
```

Note that concatenating variables in a SQL statement is bad practice, and opens up your code to SQL injection attacks. Instead, use parameters, as in:

```
$1::date 
    - kokyaku1Information2.mail_jyushin::int * interval '1 day' 
    AS modified_date
```